# All controllers return 404 of Cpanel excempt SiteController actionIndex

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-basic-app

i upload all of my web folder to the root
and then move all my project to inside a folder
and fixed all the addresses in the main index.php

every thing works fine but i dont know for what reason this happens

[image: this is 404 of Cpanel not me]

But:

```
    class SiteController extends Controller
    {
           public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('index');
    }
    
  public function actionTest()
    {
        echo 'awdaw';
    }
```

|

but site index Works fine

[image]

Comment: pretty Url is Enabled

Comment: pretty Url rule is this:
  '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',

    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',

    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',

Comment: can edit your question with your pretty url? 
also the lines from your config, with this part  ['components'] => [['UrlManager" ] ]

Comment: What kind of server is this running on? Do you have rewriting rules set on it?

Comment: verify if you have the `.htaccess` file lpaced in your web accessible directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution in my htaccess file in the end my .htaccess become this and it is ok right now

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?myaxagent\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysitetesttest.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your htacess file and try to call using controller/action. Here in your case it will be site/test